# android bitmap size dependency is based on resolution or file size

Tags: android, bitmap

i have two jpg images.one image size is around 1 MB another is lower than 100KB.but both the two images has the same resolutiuon. now these images should be loaded into imageviews. the memory allocation while loading these images will be depends on filesize or resolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the resolution, not the file size. The image will be decompressed into memory when loaded, so two images of the same resolution will use the same amount of memory.

You can verify the memory usage of a Bitmap loaded into an ImageView using [getByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount()) or [getAllocationByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getAllocationByteCount()) (KitKat and above).

e.g:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
int bytesUsed = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getAllocationByteCount();
```